# What are the possible attachement for the Stun Gun and Zenith?

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

When trying to add a Laser Sight to my Stun Gun, I got a warning that I would not be able to replace it with something else.

While it doesn't surprise me, I was wondering what else was possible to add on the Stun Gun, which is already silenced.

Also, in HR, it was possible to have Laser Sight and Silencer on the same 10mm Pistol, but I only see one attachement point on it,will I have to choose between them now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning message doesn't mean that you're sacrificing some other attachment option on the gun in question; it just means that you can't remove the attachment later if you find another gun that you'd prefer to stick it on.

In fact, Mankind Divided supports multiple simultaneous attachments in the same slot, and you can swap back and forth between them or even "deactivate" them entirely.  On the combat rifle, for example, you can add both a 4x scope and a Holosight, and then swap between either of those or even back to iron sights on the fly.  Similarly, if you attach a laser or silencer, you can "remove" them (but not actually separate them from the gun) at any time.

To answer your question then, the Stun Gun supports only a laser attachment.  The Zenith supports a silencer and a laser.  In both cases you're not sacrificing anything by attaching them, and you can "deactivate" and "reactivate" them at any time.

(I think the little attachment boxes for each gun in the inventory screen are broken.  I definitely have some guns where I've added all possible attachments and yet there's still an empty box showing.)

P.S. Actually, I'm using the preorder "special" Zenith model (with burst fire).  It's possible that the regular Zenith doesn't have slots for both laser and silencer, but I would bet that it does.